# Admob not showing ads when limited ad tracking is activated

Tags: ios, admob

Ok the problem here is that some devices are not able to see the ads, and after some revision on the devices and some discard process I found that the devices with "Limited Ad Tracking" won't show any ads. Other SDKs as iron source allow you to call the ad without IDFA in iOS, as far as I know the IDFA won't be used when "Limited Ad Tracking" is on so I guess Admob uses this as a needed element for requesting ads. I hope someone knows how to request ads when "Limited Ad Tracking" is on. Here is my code:

```
//MARK: - Request AD
var rewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd?

func requestAd(){

    rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()

    rewardBasedVideo?.delegate = self
    rewardBasedVideo?.load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-9505104597698750/8748625825")

}

//Show Video (This function is called on a button action)
func showVideo(){

    rewardBasedVideo?.present(fromRootViewController: self)

}
```

Comment: upload your log in question to see what response you get in case of limited ad tracking